# How best to use or to emulate the "obsolete" Combinatorica command Contract?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorica

The obsolete Combinatorica package has a command `Contract` for contracting an edge in a graph.
Below is my very clunky attempt to work with up-to-date graph objects and yet use the `Contract` command from Combinatorica. The idea is to convert into and out of adjaceny matrices.

My questions are:

Is there a modern analogue of the `Contract` command ?

If not, then would readers advise me to continue working with the Combinatorica `Contract` command, or to write my own command for contracting edges, and not bother trying to use Combinatorica ?

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]

graph = System`Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]

convertgraphtocombinatoricastyle[graph_] := Module[{},
FromAdjacencyMatrix[Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[graph]]]];

combinatoricastylegraph = convertgraphtocombinatoricastyle[graph];
ShowGraph[combinatoricastylegraph, VertexLabel -> True]

contractedcombinatoricagraph = 
Contract[combinatoricastylegraph, {1, 2}];
ShowGraph[contractedcombinatoricagraph, VertexLabel -> True]
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`EdgeContract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeContract.html)?

Comment: Is that new in version 10 ? I only have 9 :D Aha ! I see that it is indeed new in version 10. Thank you for your response, hftf !

Comment: Version 9 doesn't support multigraphs, so you can't reproduce exactly the same behavior

Comment: Thank you, belisarius is forth. I remember that I wrote code to deal with multigraphs before. I represented them by their adjacency matrices, but the elements of the matrices were lists, corresponding to a labeling of the (possibly many) edges between pairs of vertices.